# Not working as expected when reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm very new to .NET and I'm getting confused with XMLs! I'm trying to make an app for Windows Phone 7, but code fails when trying to read XML. According to the expression watcher e.Result is ok.

Here is the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Arrives>
  <Arrive>
    <IdStop>803</IdStop>
    <idLine>44</idLine>
    <IsHead>True</IsHead>
    <Destination>MARQUES DE VIANA</Destination>
    <IdBus>0000</IdBus>
    <TimeLeftBus>405</TimeLeftBus>
    <DistanceBus>978</DistanceBus>
    <PositionXBus>-1</PositionXBus>
    <PositionYBus>-1</PositionYBus>
    <PositionTypeBus>1</PositionTypeBus>
  </Arrive>
  <Arrive>
    <IdStop>803</IdStop>
    <idLine>12</idLine>
    <IsHead>True</IsHead>
    <Destination>MARQUES ZAFRA</Destination>
    <IdBus>0000</IdBus>
    <TimeLeftBus>466</TimeLeftBus>
    <DistanceBus>1016</DistanceBus>
    <PositionXBus>-1</PositionXBus>
    <PositionYBus>-1</PositionYBus>
    <PositionTypeBus>1</PositionTypeBus>
  </Arrive>
  <Arrive>
    <IdStop>803</IdStop>
    <idLine>44</idLine>
    <IsHead>True</IsHead>
    <Destination>MARQUES DE VIANA</Destination>
    <IdBus>0000</IdBus>
    <TimeLeftBus>1077</TimeLeftBus>
    <DistanceBus>2714</DistanceBus>
    <PositionXBus>-1</PositionXBus>
    <PositionYBus>-1</PositionYBus>
    <PositionTypeBus>1</PositionTypeBus>
  </Arrive>
  <Arrive>
    <IdStop>803</IdStop>
    <idLine>12</idLine>
    <IsHead>True</IsHead>
    <Destination>MARQUES ZAFRA</Destination>
    <IdBus>0000</IdBus>
    <TimeLeftBus>1089</TimeLeftBus>
    <DistanceBus>3260</DistanceBus>
    <PositionXBus>-1</PositionXBus>
    <PositionYBus>-1</PositionYBus>
    <PositionTypeBus>1</PositionTypeBus>
  </Arrive>
</Arrives>
```

And here is the code in C# using System.Xml.Linq & System.Collections:

```
 XElement xmlEMTStop = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            foreach (XElement arriveElement in xmlEMTStop.Descendants())
            {
                // Recojemos los elementos en el XML
                stopElement readElement = new stopElement();
                readElement.idStop = (string)arriveElement.Element("idStop").Value;
                readElement.idLine = (string)arriveElement.Element("idLine").Value;
                readElement.destination = (string)arriveElement.Element("Destination").Value;
                readElement.timeLeftBusRaw = (string)arriveElement.Element("TimeLeftBus").Value;
(...)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `System.Xml.XPath` for this.

Comment: What do you mean the code "fails"? What do you expect to happen that doesn't?

Comment: what's e? how do you declare it? initialize it?

Comment: @JordanKaye: Why? LINQ to XML is almost always easier in my experience - and this looks like a very simple query.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess it differs from person to person. I have always found reading XML to be easiest using XPath. In any event your posted answer is correct, so I doubt my comment will be paid much attention ;)

Comment: At **readElement.idStop = (string)arriveElement.Element("idStop").Value;** i get a NullReferenceException. I spent a lot of time reading things about xml.linq but I can not see where the problem is. :-(

Comment: @AntoniodelaIglesia: Yes, you'll get an exception because there's no element called `idStop`. It's case-sensitive.

Comment: @JordanKaye: The benefit with LINQ to XML is that you're not working in a "language within a language" to the same extent. If I have a syntax error in XPath, I don't get to find that out until I run it (or I try it in a separate tool). In C#, I'll get the error straight away. It's also easier to write complex conditions, transformations etc within a more familiar language. I have the same aversion to embedding SQL in code too, btw :) See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/code-and-data.aspx for more details of my feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for *all* the descendants - but then *assuming* that they'll have `idStop`, `idLine` etc sub-elements. You should be asking for all the `Arrive` elements, by the looks of it:

```
foreach (XElement arriveElement in xmlEMTStop.Descendants("Arrive"))
```

Next, you need to know that LINQ to XML is case-sensitive. So this:

```
readElement.idStop = (string)arriveElement.Element("idStop").Value;
```

should be:

```
readElement.idStop = arriveElement.Element("IdStop").Value;
```

Or just:

```
readElement.idStop = (string) arriveElement.Element("IdStop");
```

Or:
        readElement.idStop = arriveElement.Element("IdStop").Value;

(The `Value` property already returns `string`, but an alternative is to invoke the explicit conversion between `XElement` and `string`.)

Next, it's not clear what you're doing with the elements once you've created them, but if you're trying to create a collection of them, you can use LINQ again:

```
var query = XElement.Parse(e.Result)
                    .Descendants("Arrive")
                    .Select(x => new StopElement {
                                IdStop = (string) x.Element("IdStop"),
                                IdLine = (string) x.Element("IdLine"),
                                Destination = (string) x.Element("Destination"),
                                TimeLeftBus = (string) x.Element("TimeLeftBus")
                            })
                    .ToList();
```

Note that I've changed the capitalization of your type and property names to follow .NET conventions. You may also want to change the *type* of some of your properties - e.g. `TimeLeftBus` looks like it's a numeric type of some kind.

Comment: I feel dumb. I promise you I've looked several times upper and lower case, but I have not seen the "i". Thank you very much, really.

Answer (score 0):

try smth like

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

var arrivesItems = from c in doc.Root.Descendants("Arrive") select c;

foreach (var item in arrivesItems) {

var idStop = item.Element("idStop").Value;
...

}
```